# Kendo Angular2 Input Component Broken on AOT Build

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a simple app utilizing the Kendo UI controls for Angular2. I also AOT compile my application. Everything was working fine until I ran an npm update and the controls were updated.

Since the update the AOT build fails. In particular the failures seem to be related to the kendo-angular-inputs component. Furthermore npm start no longer runs cleanly.  By "cleanly" I mean I should be able to issue a run command to jump between JIT/AOT versions of the app seamlessly. This, however, is not the case. I will try and describe the situation below:

**Partially Working Version**

Application with version 0.15.3 of kendo-angular-inputs installed

1. NPM Start (before a AOT build command has been issued)

   **Success, app runs**
2. Stop lite-Server, run: NPM AOT build

   **Success, app builds and runs**
3. Stop lite-Server, run: NPM Start (after a AOT build command has been issued)

   **Error**

> aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(203,41):
>   error TS2341: Property 'widgetClass' is private and only accessible
>   within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(208,41):
>   error TS2341: Property 'numericClass' is private and only accessible
>   within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(242,48):
>   error TS2445: Property 'hostBlur' is protected and only accessible
>   within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent' and its subclasses.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(490,46):
>   error TS2341: Property 'focused' is private and only accessible within
>   class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/intl.module.ngfactory.ts(28,122):
>   error TS2339: Property 'string' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   "C:/0/Health/Dashboard-lite/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/node_modules/@prog...'.

At this point the only thing I can do is run the AOT version of the application.  The JIT version will not run unless I delete the following files (I think these are all the files within the AOT compile that reference the kendo-angular-inputs component):

> AOT/APP
>
> AOT/@progress
>
> AOT/@telerik

**Non Working Version**

Application with version 0.18.6 of kendo-angular-inputs installed

1. NPM Start (before a AOT build command has been issued)

   **Success, app runs**
2. Stop lite-Server, run: NPM AOT build

   **Error**

> Error at
>   C:/Dashboard-lite/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/slider/slider-ticks.component.ngfactory.ts:87:7:
>   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. Error
>   at
>   C://Dashboard-lite/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/slider/slider.component.ngfactory.ts:207:7:
>   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

3. Try and run: NPM Start since AOT is not working (after a AOT build command has been issued)

   **Error**

> aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/maskedtextbox/maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(275,35):
>   error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/maskedtextbox/maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(279,35):
>   error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/maskedtextbox/maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(283,35):
>   error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(195,41):
>   error TS2341: Property 'widgetClass' is private and only accessible
>   within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(200,41):
>   error TS2341: Property 'numericClass' is private and only accessible
>   within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(214,48):
>   error TS2445: Property 'hostBlur' is protected and only accessible
>   within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent' and its subclasses.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/slider/slider-ticks.component.ngfactory.ts(87,7):
>   error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.
>   aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/slider/slider.component.ngfactory.ts(207,7):
>   error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.

Again, at this point I must delete the same AOT files in order to get the JIT version to run. I cannot AOT compile.

A little more info:

1. I have set up AOT compilation according to the angular.io [cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).
2. I am successfully using kendo-angular-charts. JIT/AOT versions working great.
3. I'm not sure of the version of the control I was running before the npm update.
4. I jumped back to version 0.15.3 only because versions 0.18.5 and 0.18.4 were also giving me errors.
5. I don't know if I'm really asking a question or simply trying to point out that there might be something wrong with the kendo-angular-inputs component.

Comment: Forgot to include the following dependency versions:

"@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.9.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
@telerik/kendo-draggable@^1.2.0"
@telerik/kendo-inputs-common@^2.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

The `@progress/kendo-angular-inputs` package has several newer versions that addressed several AOT issues.

Could you try `0.18.7 (2017-02-10)` version? It at least addresses the problems related to the private members and mismatched signature types.

Comment: My Results from the 0.18.7 version: 
Same results as with version 0.15.3.  At least now I can AOT compile. However, if I want to run the JIT version again I must delete compiled folders in order to get it to run.

1. NPM Start - Works
2. AOT Compile - Works
3. NPM Start - Error

Comment: Here is the error: aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/maskedtextbox/maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts(275,35): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. etc,...

Comment: This definitely sounds to a missing `ngOnChanges` params. Nevertheless, this was addressed in `0.18.7`. It could be either cache or something else that we cannot replicate locally.
Could you share a runnable app that replicates the issue? You can open an issue in https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues.